# Free with a string not clearing the string in C?

Tags: c, string, malloc, free

I'm trying to read lines from a file with words separated by commas and supposed to keep each section separated by those commas then print out certain ones. It works in a general sense, but I use a stringcpy variable that I malloc to put the comma-separated section into, and it's mallocing correctly and all, but it's not actually clearing when I free it. When I use the stringcpy again, it just rewrites the old one and keeps all the old characters I don't overwrite. Here's the bulk code, my output, and expected output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>




typedef struct airdata{
    char *siteNum;
    char *LocalID;
    char *portName;
    char *city;
    char *state;
    char *lat;
    char *lon;
    char *Tower;
} airdata;

void printData(airdata *);

int main(int arga, char **argb){
    char *filename = argb[1];

    FILE *fin = fopen(filename, "rw");
    if(fin == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "error opening file.");
        return -1;
    }
    //      else{
    //      printf("found and opened file.\n");
    //  }
    char buff[10000];
    int m = 0;
    for(m = 0; m < 10000; m++){
        buff[m] = '$';
    }
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fin)){
        char stringlist[19][100];
        //fprintf(stdout, "%s", buff);
        struct airdata * data = malloc(sizeof(airdata));
        data->siteNum = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
        data->LocalID = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
        data->portName = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
        data->city = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
        data->state = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
        data->lat = malloc(sizeof(char)*70);
        data->lon = malloc(sizeof(char)*70);
        data->Tower = malloc(sizeof(char)*1);
        int i = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int dot = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 19; i++){
            char * stringcpy = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
            x = 0;
            while(buff[dot] != ','){
                stringcpy[x] = buff[dot];
//                printf("%c ", buff[dot]);
//                printf("%c\n", stringcpy[x]);
                //printf();
                dot++;
                x++;
                if(buff[dot] == '$'){
                    break;
                }
            }
            //printf("%s\n", stringcpy);
            strcpy(stringlist[i], stringcpy);
            free(stringcpy);
            //printf("%s\n", stringlist[2]);
            //printf("\n");
            //printf(" %d\n", x);
            dot++;
            //printf("%s ", stringlist[i]);
        }

        strcpy(data->siteNum, stringlist[0]);
        strcpy(data->LocalID, stringlist[1]);
        strcpy(data->portName, stringlist[2]);
        strcpy(data->city, stringlist[3]);
        strcpy(data->state, stringlist[4]);
        strcpy(data->lat, stringlist[8]);
        strcpy(data->lon, stringlist[9]);
        strcpy(data->Tower, stringlist[14]);
        printData(data);
        free(data);
        for(m = 0; m < 10000; m++){
            buff[m] = '$';
        }

    }
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;

}

void printData(airdata * entry){
    printf("%-12s %-11s %-42s %-34s %-3s %-15s %-16s %s\n",
           entry->siteNum, entry->LocalID, entry->portName, entry->city, entry->state,
           entry->lat, entry->lon, entry->Tower);
}
```

Expected output:

```
FAA Site     Short Name  Airport Name                               City                               ST  Latitude        Longitude        Tower
========     ==========  ============                               ====                               ==  ========        =========        =====
03406.20*H   2FD7        AIR ORLANDO                                ORLANDO                            FL  28-26-08.0210N  081-28-23.2590W  N
03406.36*H   2FL5        BROOKSVILLE INTL AIRWAYS- INC              ORLANDO                            FL  28-25-26.0000N  081-27-35.0000W  N
03406.18*H   32FL        MEYER                                      ORLANDO                            FL  28-30-05.0120N  081-26-39.2560W  N
03406.11*H   37FA        FLORIDA HOSPITAL                           ORLANDO                            FL  28-34-32.0020N  081-22-06.2490W  N
03406.31*H   3FD5        ARNOLD PALMER HOSPITAL                     ORLANDO                            FL  28-31-21.0090N  081-22-49.2520W  N
```

My output:

```
03406.20*H   2FD76.20*H  AIR ORLANDO                                ORLANDOANDO                        FLLANDOANDO 28-26-08.0210N  081-28-23.2590W  NON-NPIAS.2590W
03406.36*H   2FL56.36*H  BROOKSVILLE INTL AIRWAYS- INC              ORLANDOILLE INTL AIRWAYS- INC      FLLANDOILLE INTL AIRWAYS- INC 28-25-26.0000NTL AIRWAYS- INC 081-27-35.0000WL AIRWAYS- INC NON-NPIAS.0000WL AIRWAYS- INC
03406.18*H   32FL6.18*H  MEYER.18*H                                 ORLANDO8*H                         FLLANDO8*H 28-30-05.0120N  081-26-39.2560W  NON-NPIAS.2560W
03406.11*H   37FA6.11*H  FLORIDA HOSPITAL                           ORLANDO HOSPITAL                   FLLANDO HOSPITAL 28-34-32.0020NAL 081-22-06.2490WL NON-NPIAS.2490WL
03406.31*H   3FD56.31*H  ARNOLD PALMER HOSPITAL                     ORLANDOPALMER HOSPITAL             FLLANDOPALMER HOSPITAL 28-31-21.0090NHOSPITAL 081-22-49.2520WOSPITAL NON-NPIAS.2520WOSPITAL
```

I know it's kind of hard to decipher, but you can see that my output has all the correct output in it, just if the section is smaller than the one previous, it just rewrites it and prints the old one. Shouldn't stringcpy be empty because I freed it within the loop?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks like you didn't free all the members of `data` that you `malloc`ed.  You only freed `data` itself.

Comment: But wouldn't that free everything in data too? Or do I just need to free everything inside data first then free data as a whole?

Comment: right before `strcpy(stringlist[i], stringcpy);` you need to terminate the `stringcpy` variable, try `stringcpy[x]='\0';`

Comment: You need to explicitly free everything.

Comment: Do you expect free() to do anything to the content of the freed memory? E.g. do you expect the memory to be null-filled afterwards?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons and cleblanc, those worked, thanks!!